# Get first and last object in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My example:

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="here" id="dsf">a</div>
    <div class="no" id="sdf">b</div>
    <div class="here" id="sdfsdf">c</div>
    <div class="here" id="dssdf">d</div>
    <div class="no" id="ds3f">e</div>
    <div class="here" id="ds4f">f7</div>
    <div class="no" id="tert4">b8</div>
    <div class="no" id="r4tt4">5c</div>
    <div class="here" id="ert4">d4</div>
    <div class="no" id="fdgd4">e3</div>
    <div class="here" id="fghf3">2f</div>
</div>
```

```js
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
if(rand > 5){
    var here = $('div div.here');
} else {
    var here = $('div div.no');
}

console.log(here);
```

How can I get the first and last elements from "here"? I would like get the ID of these elements.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/5BfPL/2/

Comment: What about `here.first()` and `here.last()`???

Comment: `$('div .here').first().attr('id')` and `$('div .here').last().attr('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using jQuerys[`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

`.first()` : Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set.
`.last()` : Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

With those to you can select retrieve the element. Than you can just use `.prop()` or `.attr()` (depending on your jQuery version) to get the `id`.

Example::

```
var firstElement = $('div div.here').first().prop('id');

var lastElement = $('div div.here').last().prop('id');
```

<kbd>**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BfPL/4/)**</kbd>

#### Update

As per your request in the comment, you can get the 3th element using the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

`.eq()` : Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Example:

```
var thirdElement= $('div div.here').eq(2); // the parameter is 0-based.
```

Comment: Updated the answer as per your request.